# Текущая нагрузка на диск из /proc/diskstats

Tags: linux

Как взять текущую нагрузку на чтение и запись на диск из /proc/diskstats? Готовые программы по типу iostat мне не нужны

Comment: `grep+sed+awk`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Делаешь 2 замера. Вычитаешь и делишь на время между замерами.

или парси текстовый файл `/proc/diskstats` https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/ABI/testing/procfs-diskstats

или отдельно по дискам `/sys/block/<dev>/stat` https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/block/stat.rst